# Does forecasting with ARIMA lose non-stationary components?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, stationarity

Suppose I have a time series $Y$. I have read that an ARIMA model consists as an ARMA model of a stationarized version of $Y$.

If I try to predict $n$ ticks ahead with an ARIMA forecast model (with $n$ big), would I loose any non-stationary component of $Y$ like trend or seasonality ?

Comment: No you don't, because part of the ARIMA process is reverse transforming the forecasts after they are generated.

Answer (score 0):

Not if done correctly . Note non-stationarity can be (is) a symptom of a series with more than one level OR more than 1 trend OR more than 1 model error variance OR more than 1 set of model parameters OR needed Seasonal Pulses manifested/existent in the observed data.